# Simulating Keyboard with SendInput C#

Tags: c#, directx, sendinput

I tried to simulate a key from the keyboard for a direct x game with this code:

```
public static void Send(short Keycode)
{
    INPUT[] InputData = new INPUT[1];

    InputData[0].type = 1;
    InputData[0].ki.wScan = Keycode;
    InputData[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP | KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    InputData[0].ki.time = 0;
    InputData[0].ki.dwExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero;

    SendInput(1, InputData, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));
}
```

The problem is, this does not simulate the key. The key isn't pressed.

Comment: Yes i tried this, then it simulate the key, but the key isn't released after this.

Comment: try to send both events in succession. first down, then up (with a little pause in between)

Comment: Thanks this is the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send a `KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN` and then a `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP` event in order for the game to correctly process the key events.

Leave a little pause in between the sending of the key events.

This is needed if the game is polling the keys, it then has time to recognize the pressed key.